# How to access value from a table for which there is no direct relationship?

Tags: powerbi, dax

My model has got date table, users table. There is a 1:M relation between date and sales. And 1:M relation between date and budget.

Also 1:M relation between user and sales. And 1:M relation between user and budget.

For each year/month/day, I want to calculate the SUMX ( salesamt / budget_alloc )

So I have created a table visual and dragged date into it (from date table). Now made a measure with formula:

SUMX ( sales, DIVIDE(salesamt, SUM ( RELATEDTABLE ( budget[budget_alloc] ) ) ) )

Is this right way to access the budget_alloc value (located in budget table) by measure doing sumx on sales table? There is no direct relation between sales and budget, the relation goes via the date table. I want to check because I have read that table expansion happens towards the 1 side. So looking at the sales table (measure formula) the 1 side is the date table. So will RELATEDTABLE be able to give the measure access to the budget table (and ensuring that budget table respects the date table filter)?

Comment: No, this is an incorrect approach. You should iterate a table (or tables) shared between sales and budget (i.e, "Date"), on a desired level of granularity (year, year-month, year-day, etc). For example, assuming you have measures [Sale Amount] and [Budget Amount], you can write: SUMX( VALUES(Date[Year-Month]), DIVIDE([Sale Amount], [Budget Amount]))

Comment: But what if I want to make it for month, and also allow drilldown by day, can I use VALUES(Date[Date])? Also, could you tell me what my formula would logically mean?

Comment: You should choose the lowest granularity level you need to report, in this case year-day. The formula will then work on all higher grains (month, quarter, year, etc). Your formula does not make sense - you are iterating the wrong table, and trying to access relationship that does not exist (between sales and budget).

Comment: Thanks. Regarding my formula I was thinking that for a day it will sumx on each row by dividing salesamt in that row with sum of budgetamt (since the same date filter will be applied). But when instead of day we look at month, then salesamt for that row will be divided by sum of budgetamt for all days in the month which is wrong so thanks for the help.